# List view using array list with name image date in flutter

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, view

How to get data from static or dynamic list and set to list view or grid view[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your list of data into a ListView of widgets you can map the data list to your resultant widget list. Follow the code below:

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {

  List<Data> dataList = [
    Data(name: "Demo name",date: DateTime.now(),description: "Dummy long description",imageURL: 'https://m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-sport-seo-meta/1.20.8/images/bbc-sport-logo.png'),
    Data(name: "Demo name",date: DateTime.now(),description: "Dummy long description",imageURL: 'https://m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-sport-seo-meta/1.20.8/images/bbc-sport-logo.png'),
    Data(name: "Demo name",date: DateTime.now(),description: "Dummy long description",imageURL: 'https://m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-sport-seo-meta/1.20.8/images/bbc-sport-logo.png'),
    Data(name: "Demo name",date: DateTime.now(),description: "Dummy long description",imageURL: 'https://m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-sport-seo-meta/1.20.8/images/bbc-sport-logo.png'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: dataList.map((data){
            return Container(
              width: width,height: 80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.5,color: Colors.black))),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(width: 50,height: 50,decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(data.imageURL))),),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: [
                      Text(data.name),
                      Expanded(child: Text(data.description)),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text(data.date.toString());
                ],
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Data {

  String name;
  String imageURL;
  String description;
  DateTime date;

  Data({this.name,this.imageURL,this.date,this.description});

}
```

Check the above code based on your requirement.

Comment: Can u do this using array like.     "Imgurl",text, description,date.  Date should be at right side

Comment: @aaloksingh Check the new code I've posted in my answer.

Comment: Thanks  it helps me alot.

Answer (score 0):

List dataList = [
Data(
name: "Title",date: "12/03/2021",description: "Description",imageURL:'https://m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-sport-seo-meta/1.20.8/images/bbc-sport-logo.png'),
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double width = MediaQuery
.of(context)
.size
.width;
double height = MediaQuery
.of(context)
.size
.height;

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    bottomOpacity: 0.0,
    elevation: 0.0,
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF104C57),
    title: new Text("Notification"),
    leading: new IconButton(
      icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
    ),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0, right: 7.0),
        child: Container(

          width: width,
          height: height,
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: dataList.map((data) {
              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6.0, right: 6.0, top: 10.0),
                width: width,
                height: 80,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Color(0xFFDCDADB),
                    width: 0.5,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 65,
                      height: 65,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: ExactAssetImage(
                              'lib/images/notificationicon.png',
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 145,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            data.name,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12.0,
                              //fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              color: Color(0xFF75778A),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                data.description,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  //fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  color: Color(0xFF868C9A),
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Date : ",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                color: Color(0xFF868C9A),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              data.date,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                color: Color(0xFF6A7180),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(00)),
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: ExactAssetImage('lib/images/homebg.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

class Data {
String name,imageURL,description,date;

Data({this.name, this.imageURL, this.date, this.description});
}